# Excel macro that open and prepares Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a code that open access from excel:

```
Dim objShell As Object

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.Open "\\acrtnd\share$\PUBLIC\!tools\preportDST.accdb"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

I would like to little automatized that and add to it code that will paste value in to field in access and run macro in access that start calculation, but I have not knowidge about manageing other office parts from inside excel. The text box name is "txt_PasteField" and VBA macro in access is name "run_calculation", I try something like this below but objShell do not allow such actions.

```
Dim objShell As Object

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.Open "\\acrtnd\share$\PUBLIC\!tools\preportDST.accdb"
     objShell.txt_PasteField.Value = Sheets("dashboard").Cells(5, 1).Value
     call objShell.run_calculation 
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Can someone provide be way to do that or navigate me to needed command?
Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to help you, but I'm still a little unclear on the details. Since a text field has to be either on a form or a report, you have to open it first. Also, if you want to influence the Access application after opening it, you will need to use OLE automation.

```vb
Dim appAccess As Object
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With appAccess
    .OpenCurrentDatabase "\\acrtnd\share$\PUBLIC\!tools\preportDST.accdb"
    .UserControl = True
    .DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm"
    .Forms!MyForm.txt_PasteField.Value = Sheets("dashboard").Cells(5, 1).Value
    .Run "run_calculation"
End With
```

Comment: Yea, thanks. I do not provide form as I do not know that. It is form "p_Main". Your solution is almost working beside this that I cannot run the macro. I investigate that this macro is inside "Microsoft Access Class Object" in "Form_p_Main" and should be run in that usserform (which is open from beginning) but `.Run "run_calculation"` do not work, I was trying with  `.DoCmd.RunMacro "run_calculation"` and try to refer `"p_Main!run_calculation"` but failed

Comment: Are you using a vba sub, vba function, or macro, and where is it located?

Comment: Originally this is function in that access file VBA_preportDST/Microsoft Access Class Object/Form_p_Main  (like modules in excel vba project). But I also try to made subs inside that access file that call that function but it not helping, I do not know how to run it from excel, how to address it or something

Comment: You either need to put your code inside a normal module, and inside a function (not sub) and then you can use `.run`, or you can put them in your form as a publicly accessible method, but that requires a little more code

Comment: I cannot do much with function in access at it is doing too many things there, I put whole code that open acces in to function in module, and call it in sheet but it also do not help. It open access, paste value to correct place and cannot run calculation function

Comment: You don't need to do things with the code in Access. But you do need to tell me where it's located if you want my help

Comment: Ok, so `Function run_calculation` that I need to call is in VisualBasic in Access (Alt+F11) in Project "VBA_preportDST" in that file in tab "Microsoft Access Class Object" in that "object" "Form_p_Main" and I try tu run it with `.run` from ms excel VBA function/sub or what is need

Comment: Is it defined as a sub or function? Is it public, private or protected?

Comment: `run_calculation ` is a function and it does not matter if it will be public or not (currently public) and macro in excel originally was sub, I moved it to vba module in excel modules and create as a function but it also not helping

Comment: ... It does matter if it's public or not if you want me to write code that calls it. Just share the code. I'm about to give up on this problem.

Comment: `Function OpenDST()`;   

    `Dim prTool As Object`;   
    `Set prTool = CreateObject("Access.Application")`;   
        
    `prTool.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\acrtnd\share$\PUBLIC\!tools\preportDST.accdb"`;   
    `prTool.UserControl = True`;   
    `prTool.DoCmd.OpenForm "p_Main"`;   
    `prTool.Forms!p_Main.txt_PasteField.Value = Sheets("dashboard").Cells(5, 1).Value`;   
    `prTool.Run "run_calculation"`;   

`End Function`;   there is not possible to include separate lines in comment so I add it in this way

Comment: Not the code I've just written for you, the code you want to call to do the calculation, of course.

Comment: It is too long to bring it here, it also call many additional subs and functions inside :(